# How to manipulate array of strings via function in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm trying to write code that reads 42 strings from stdin using a function, with knowing how many strings I have saved.
Here is what I came up with so far:

```
#define rows 42
#define chars 101

void populate(int* citiesCount, char cities[][chars]);

int main()
{
    char cities[rows][chars]; //array of strings to store all lines of txt file
    int citiesCount = 0; //how many lines there really are (may be less than 42)

    populate(&citiesCount, cities);

    //print all cities
    printf("NUMBER OF CITIES: %d\n", citiesCount);
    for(int i = 0; i < citiesCount; i++)
    {
        printf("CITY: %s\n", cities[i]);
    }
    printf("END\n");

    return 0;
}

void populate(int* citiesCount, char cities[][chars])
{
    char cntrl;
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", *citiesCount);
        scanf("%100[^\n]", &cities[*citiesCount++]); //read line of txt file and save it to array of strings
        printf("%s\n", cities[i]);
        cntrl = getchar(); //check, if I'm at end of file, if yes break loop
        if(cntrl == EOF)
            break;
    }
}
```

Code is compiled by following statement

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Werror proj1.c -o proj1
```

In this project it is **forbidden** to use dynamic memory allocation.

If I try to compile code, I get the following error:

`"'%[^' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[101]'"`

I tried every possible way to deal with it, but couldn't find anything wat works.

Comment: `scanf("%100[^\n]", &cities[*citiesCount++]);` --> `scanf("%100[^\n]",  cities[(*citiesCount)++]); `

Comment: I removed ampersand, now code compiles, but after first line it crashes.

Comment: @xing `*citiesCount++` should be `(*citiesCount)++`

Comment: After replacing *citiesCount++ with (*citiesCount)++ code works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: cntrl = getchar(); this returns int

Answer (score 0):

If you are not too keen on using the scanf this one should help

```
void populate(int* citiesCount, char cities[][chars])
{
    for(int i = 0; ( i < rows ) && fgets( cities[i], chars, stdin) ; i++)
    {
        // remove there if not required.
        printf("%d\n", (*citiesCount)++ );
        printf("%s\n", cities[i]);

    }
}
```